# How to convert this excel column to python dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

Here is a table of calculations I am doing in excel. Is it possible to do the same using python? If yes, can anyone help me do the same. Column B is the sensor data I get continously. column A is the sl no associated with data. column C is average of 3 data values(C4==AVERAGE(B2:B4))(Lets say window of 3 elements). column D is maximum among the same 3 data values(D4==MAX(B2:B4))(window average). column E checks if the value in column D is repeated twice in succession (value repeated in two consecutive windows). To fill the value in column F: If column E has an entry as Yes, match the row from B such that, value in B is same as value in D(which is the max value of 3 values of first group under consideration(Here window 3 and 4 has same highest value - 6. find the first occurrence of 6 in window 3 and not its sl no in column F). column F will have the value picked from column A corresponding to this B row) (F7 =IF(E7='yes',INDEX(A4:A6,MATCH(D7,B4:B6,0),1),""))
so all 6 columns are interrelated. whats the best way to handle this in python? my data points runs in million. Thanks in advance.

| slno | data | avg | max | Repeating twice | data no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |  |
| 4 | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 5 | 4.3 | 6 | yes | 5 |
| 7 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | 6 | 5.3 | 6 |  |  |
| 10 | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | 4 | 4.0 | 5 | yes | 10 |
| 13 | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | 5 | 3.7 | 5 |  |  |
| 16 | 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 17 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 18 | 4 | 3.0 | 4 |  |  |

Currently I am getting data in python(list)(coulmn B) which needs to be processed and analysed(automatically fill other columns). When data was small, I copied data in excel and do the calculations in excel. I am facing problem as the data points are increasing. I am not able to find a solution in python to fill the last column. I tried using lists and arrays but not able to link each other. I am not able to fill last column. I have not used dataframes before as well.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent sometime learning panda dataframes for finance a few years ago. Give this a try and see if it works for you.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read data from a CSV file and store it in a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Calculate the rolling average and maximum using a rolling window of 3
df['avg'] = df['data'].rolling(3).mean()
df['max'] = df['data'].rolling(3).max()
df['prev_max'] = df['max'].shift(1)
df['next_max'] = df['max'].shift(-1)

# Check if the maximum value is repeated twice in succession
df['repeating_twice'] = ((df['prev_max'] == df['max']) & (df['next_max'] == df['max']))

# Fill the last column based on the previous calculations
df['data_no'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[df['max'] == x['max']].iloc[0]['slno'] if x['repeating_twice'] else '', axis=1)

# Write the output back to a CSV file
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I tried the above suggestion. rolling mean is filling the column 'avg', 'max'. because of this, repeating_twice is getting filled with wrong values.

Comment: I've just updated it. Try again.

Comment: Still the column avg and max get all the values with new code. here is the work around what i am thinking. I will use multiple dataframes. df1 -> sl no, data; df2 -> winno, list of 3rows of data, avg, max, repeatinftwice.